# POST запрос http

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, http, post

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с непонятной мне проблемой...
Написал простенький http сервер на Ubuntu 22 + python3 и ловлю на нем POST- запросом файлы... не понимаю по какой причине, но тот же код на одном сервере Ubuntu принимает все без проблем, а на втором жалуется на размеры больших файлов. Я так понимаю, дело в конфигурациях, но нигде не смог найти ответ. Вот мой код сервера:

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
        data = self.rfile.read(int(length))
        ip = self.client_address[0]
        with open("missing.txt", "wb") as file:
            file.write(data)
        self.send_response(200)
        threading.Thread(target=thread_import_DB, args=(ip,)).start()

httpd = HTTPServer(('11.11.11.11', 8009), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Я знаю, что в на php сервере можно менять post_max_size, есть ли что-то подобное на python?